# How to resolve ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

I have been trying to create a deck of cards using this code:

```
public DeckOfCards()
{
    //constructor fills deck of Cards 
        String faces[] = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve" }; 
        String suits[] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" }; 

        deck = new Cards[ NUMBER_OF_CARDS ]; 
        currentCard = 0; 
        randomNumbers = new Random(); 

        //populate deck with Card objects 
        for( int count = 0; count < deck.length; count++ )
            deck[ count ] = 
                    new Cards( faces[ count % 13 ], suits[ count / 13 ] ); 
    } //end DeckOfCard constructor
```

Yet, there is one error that I just cannot fix. It pops out like this: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at:

```
      for( int count = 0; count < deck.length; count++ )
        deck[ count ] = 
        new Cards( faces[ count % 13 ], suits[ count     / 13 ] );
```

Why does this error keep showing up? Any help will be greatly      appreciated.

Comment: You don't have *King* in `faces` array. And why are you naming *Eleven* instead of *Jack*?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a card (Thirteen/King) in your `faces[]` array. Right now `count % 13` will give you `an array out of bounds error` when it returns 12 because your array only has 12 elements [0-11]. Either add a `Thirteen` to your `faces` array or reduce your modulus value from 13 to 12.